# Ruby - Generate all two letter words

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to generate a array containing all two letter word combinations.

What would be the best way to generate it.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As `steenslag` points out, the quickest way is

```
('aa'..'zz').to_a
```

If your alphabet isn't 'a' through 'z', though, you can use [`Array#repeated_combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000290):

```
alphabet = %w[А Б В Г Д Е Ё Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я]
alphabet.repeated_combination(2).map(&:join) # => ["AA", "AБ", ...]
```

Or, as `Mladen` points out:

```
alphabet.product(alphabet).map(&:join)
```

*Note*: `repeated_combination` is available in Ruby 1.9.2 or with [`require 'backports/1.9.2/array/repeated_combination'`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) from my [`backports`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem.

Comment: Or, simply, `Array#product` on itself. :)

Comment: @Mladen: Indeed, and that could be useful to mix different sets of letters. Answer updated, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
('aa'..'zz').to_a
```

Converts a Range to an Array.

Comment: **This** is why I love Ruby! I had `(('a'..'z').to_a.permutation(2).map(&:join) + ('a'..'z').to_a.map{|a| a*2})`, but then I thought, *"This is a mess. I wonder if `('aa'..'zz')` would work?"* Then, I was amazed.

Comment: @Ashley: your approach is nicely generic, though, and using `repeated_combination` makes it cleaner (see my answer).