# Creating a Count With Multiple Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to create a list of numbers and letters in order from 0-9 and a-z.

I have an array of values
value_array = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d',
'e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w',
'x','y','z']

and an array for the list of combinations, in order, that these numbers can produce for x number of characters, let's say three

list_array = []

and an array for the current combination of letters and numbers (which I will turn into a string before pushing it to the list array,]

current_combo ['0','0', '0']

How do I get the value array to count up for the current combo array so that I can create arrays like"
['0','0','1']
['0','0','2']
['0','0','3']
['0','0','4']
['0','0','5']
['0','0','6']
..
..
..
['a','z','1']
..
..
and finally to ['z','z','z']?

Here is my code thus far. Sorry if it's really crazy. I'm a noob at this:

```
    exponent = test.count('?')


puts 36 ** exponent

possible_characters = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d',
'e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w',
'x','y','z']

list = []

combo = []
end_combo = []

exponent.times do |e|
  combo << '0'
  end_combo << 'z'
end

puts combo.to_s

while combo != end_combo



end
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212884/ruby-generate-all-two-letter-words

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xs = ("0".."9").to_a + ("a".."z").to_a
xs.product(xs, xs)
# [["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "1"], ..., ["z", "z", "y"], ["z", "z", "z"]]
```

As Mladen noted, with Ruby 1.9 it's even easier:

```
(("0".."9").to_a + ("a".."z").to_a).repeated_permutation(3)
```

Comment: Actually in 1.9.2 it's even easier to create the `xs` array: `[*?0..?9, *?a..?z]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  value_array.repeated_permutation(n).to_a
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a cartesian product, not a permutation.

Comment: 1.9.2 has `repeated_permutation` which should do the trick: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000289